# Why I get 'kivy.adapters' problem with kivy designer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I get an error with **`Kivy Designer`** in **`Python 3.6.8`**, when I write: `Python -m designer` it's give me this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", mod_spec)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
   File "C:\Users\Muhammad Hasan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\kivy_designer-0.1.dev0-py3.6.egg\designer\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
     from designer.app import DesignerApp
   File "C:\Users\Muhammad Hasan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\kivy_designer-0.1.dev0-py3.6.egg\designer\app.py", line 12, in <module>
     from designer.components.designer_content import DesignerContent
   File "C:\Users\Muhammad Hasan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\kivy_designer-0.1.dev0-py3.6.egg\designer\components\designer_content.py", line 5, in <module>
     from designer.uix.py_code_input import PyScrollView
   File "C:\Users\Muhammad Hasan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\kivy_designer-0.1.dev0-py3.6.egg\designer\uix\py_code_input.py", line 3, in <module>
     from designer.uix.completion_bubble import CompletionBubble
   File "C:\Users\Muhammad Hasan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\kivy_designer-0.1.dev0-py3.6.egg\designer\uix\completion_bubble.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.adapters'
```

How can I solve this problem? I try to install a lot of package that I found in internet, no thing help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy designer is an abandoned, not-remotely-finished project. It is not supported by the Kivy team, or anyone else.

This specific error is because Kivy doesn't have an adapters module any more.

Comment: Ok, so would you recommend that I use kivy?
I am a flutter programmer but I liked to dealing with Kivy on Python :)